# How to set CausesValidation to false to Close[X]box of windowsform?

Tags: c#, validation

I already set the causesvalidation to false on my cancelbutton and it working.

```
bool IsCancelBtnClicked = false;
private void EmployeeIDtextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (EmployeeIDtextBox.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter EmployeeID.", "Invalid EmployeeID");
    }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsCancelBtnClicked = true;
    EmployeeIDtextBox.Validating -= new CancelEventHandler(textBox4_Validating);
    this.Close();
}
```

or

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;
     Close();
}
```

What I need is to set CauseValidation to false in Close[X]box of windowsform?.
I already tried to set CauseValidation to false in the form itself but it did not works. Everytime I hit Close[X]box the messagebox still appears.

Comment: Use the [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) Event. If you do it there, you probably don't even need to do it in the `Click` Event of the `button3`.

Comment: @Corak How i will use FormClosing Event?

Answer (score 4):

The Form class automatically runs ValidateChildren before closing the form.  If you have any controls that set e.Cancel = true in their Validating event handler then that prevents the Close button from working.  All you have to do is to allow the form to close regardless.  Paste this code into your form's source code:

```
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        e.Cancel = false;
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
```

If you complain with MessageBox.Show() instead of ErrorProvider *and* you displayed the window with Show() instead of ShowDialog() then you need a bigger weapon.  That requires disabling validation early, before Winforms can run the ValidateChildren() method and trigger your message box.  Paste this code into the form class:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        const int WM_CLOSE = 0x10;
        if (m.Msg == WM_CLOSE) {
           base.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.Disable;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but the messagebox still appears. :(

Comment: Right, ValidateChildren() does this.  Which is a good reason to never spam a user with a message box and use the gentle ErrorProvider instead.

Comment: So it is not possible to do it with Close[X]box ? I think i have to set ControlBox to false instead. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

### **Check if the form is disposed.**

```
if (this.IsDisposed)
{
    if (EmployeeIDtextBox.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter EmployeeID.", "Invalid EmployeeID");
    }
}
```

Comment: where do I check if the form is disposed?